# getting "This Connection is Untrusted" often. with www.myopenid.com for instance

Tags: security, internet

This seems like a security problem because the sites that it complains about should (I think) be trustworthy.  For instance, I got the message trying to authenticate a login to openid.

```
This Connection is Untrusted
  You have asked Firefox to connect
 securely to www.myopenid.com, but we can't confirm that your connection is secure.
         Normally, when you try to connect securely,
sites will present trusted identification to prove that you are
going to the right place. However, this site's identity can't be verified
```

I did a full scan with MSE in safe mode and it didnt find any viruses.

Is there anything else I should do?   What I have been doing when this happens is use a different computer on my home network (which doesnt get the message).

Thanks!

DOn

Comment: Check your time and date. Make sure the date is not way off.

Comment: date and time look ok, within a couple of minutes.

Comment: The year is correct? ;)

Comment: Click the "Technical Details" option and post the specific error message here so we can help you debug it.

Comment: The year is correct on the date.

Comment: WHen I click technical details, it says "www.myopenid.com uses an invalid security certificate.  The certificate is not trusted because the issuer certificate is not trusted.  (Error code: sec_error_untrusted_issuer)."

Answer (score 0):

Given your last remark "issuer certificate is not trusted.", maybe some firewall monitors your secure (https) connections and send their own certificate instead of the website's certificate.

Click the link at the bottom of the error page: "I Understand the Risks"

Let Firefox retrieve the certificate: "Add Exception" -> "Get Certificate".

Click the "View..." button to inspect the certificate and check who is the issuer. Could it be your company or the vendor of the firewall appliance? In that case:

Only leave the mark in the box at the bottom to "Permanently store this exception" if you trust that certificate.

Click "Confirm Security Exception" to enter the site if you still want to go to that website.

If the issuer is your security software then you either have to disable that check in your firewall or install the root certificate of that firewall. See [Configure firewalls so that Firefox can access the Internet.](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/configure-firewalls-so-firefox-can-access-internet)

See also my answer to [Tracking information on HTTPS connection](https://superuser.com/questions/539281/tracking-information-on-https-connection)